# Similarity Metrics

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

I am trying to research on different metrics and found many ssimilarity metrics : Euclidean distance  Dynamic Time Warping, Edit Distance with Real
Penalty  DISSIM , Sequence Weighted Alignment model, Spatial Assembling Distance.

However I had a question : Is there any other metric that gives similarity  in a  time series manner.
I am looking for something that not only calculates similarity metric between the features but also arranges them in a Time series manner (in the order the features are received)?

For eg:  if  we have features F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,7,F8 and of them if features  F1 F2 F4 F6 F8 are similar

Is there an algorithm that gives an output  F1 F2 F4 F6 F8 are similar in this order :. ie is there an algorithm that gives result in a  series manner (in terms of time )

Thankyou!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking for an algorithm that will order the features based on which is most similar or an algorithm that takes the time the feature was "seen" into account when calculating the similarity?

Comment: I am looking for the 2nd option.  The algorithm must cluster features  based on the time it receives it.. For eg if it gets features F1- F10 , It should say features 1, features 2 ,features 4, features 6 are similar  in the order  algorithm received  the features

Comment: Can you provide any more context? Are the features represented by boolean, scalar, or some other type of values? Do you differentiate between "not seen yet" and "definitely does not have" a feature?

Answer (score 1):

The question is confusing. But for what it is worth...

Dynamic Time Warping is NOT a metric.
Spatial Assembling Distance is not a metric.

You should read http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

If you are doing time series similarity comparisons, then i am 99% sure your should use DTW. Source, I have tested more distance measures on more datasets, than the rest of the world combined. http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/time_series_data/